# Sed change not known string in one line leaving the rest untouched

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm facing problem with using sed in my project. I have a file myfile.txt with content inside like this:

```
{"Argument_date": "2020-04-16", "Argument_post": "true", "Argument_like": "false"}
```

I need to change the date argument with actual date not touching the rest of the line - but this date can be any not just **2020-04-16** - so this is unknown string

So i did this:

```
sed 's/\"Argument_date\"\: \".*\"/\"Argument_date\"\: \"'"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"'\"/g' myfile.txt
```

But I get output almost correct:

```
{"Argument_date": "2020-05-05"}
```

Sed is changing this unknown date correctly to new one from system date, but miss all the rest of the line.
Can someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong to get correct output like this:

```
{"Argument_date": "2020-05-05", "Argument_post": "true", "Argument_like": "false"}
```

Comment: Your regex in sed is matching the whole string and replacing the whole string with the new date. Put in  a regex expression that only matches the given field.

Comment: `".*"` -> `"[^"]*"`. But do not use shell on json, use a tool for json to parse json, like `jq`. Then you want have to care about any regex. Double qoutes are literal inside single quotes, just `'s/"Argument_data"...'` etc. No need for `\\`.

Comment: ".*" -> "[^"]*" - this helped a lot. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Use `jq` to manipulate json:

```
jq --arg date "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" '.Argument_date = $date'
```

Comment: Thank You for fast answer, jq i can not use, I need to run later this script on machines where i can not install jq.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your regex, it matches the whole string and then replaces it with `"Argument_date": "2020-05-05"`

Try changing your regex to match only the required part. One solution could be:

```
sed -E 's/(.*?)"Argument_date":\s+"[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+"/\1"Argument_date":"'"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"'"/g' file1
```

Comment: That did the trick it works - onestly i do not understand yet why but works ;-)

Comment: Still I don get why this what i provide not working but similar one just not touching the "unknown" works perfect for whole string leaving the rest not touched

**sed 's/\"Argument_post\"\: \"true\"/\"Argument_post\"\: \"false\"/g' myfile.txt**

Comment: Try [regexr](https://regexr.com/) or other similar websites to check what your regex does and also to debug the same. You can pass in your test data and check against it your regular expressions.